# Wordpress menu item not showing until reload

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu on a wordpress site with six different items. When I browse to the different pages the last menu item disappears. When I reload the page, the last item appears again. No CSS issue as the markup is deleted and re-rendered on reload.

Anyone knows what this is about?

**Solution**
I'm using Lawyeria-Lite theme and in the scripts.js file, my item was removed since the width of the container was too wide.

Comment: Share the site url...

Comment: Found the issue, it was the theme that removed the item with jquery..